polars causes python kernel crash on large data set
I have a largish polars dataframe, which is the cross product of two dataframes. I'm trying to use the jellyfish library to get a similarity score on two columns, like so:
vec_jw_similarity = np.vectorize(jellyfish.jaro_winkler_similarity)
cross_df.with_columns(
    (pl.struct(["title", "author", "title_right", "author_right"])
    .map_batches(
        lambda auth_title: vec_jw_similarity(
            auth_title.struct.field("title"),
            auth_title.struct.field("title_right"),
        )
    )
    ).alias("JW_similarity")
)

I've tried it on my machine and on Colab and it crashes the kernel every time, with my machine showing an error message indicating a memory leak. I've tried the jellyfish code in a loop on synthesised data that is an order of magnitude larger than my dataframe and it's run with no leak or crash, which is why I suspect it's polars, but I could be wrong.

You should use the polars_ds plugin for jaro_winkler. https://stackoverflow.com/a/79044037/ (and join_where instead of a cross join)
